# Can't use any await operation in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await

I have recently got into Flutter and I am using Android Studio and emulating on the Xcode iOS simulator. My issue is that any await task I try to call never finishes "waiting". Wether it's a location I'm trying to get or a http response. Nothing is working and it's driving me nuts.
Here's an example of something I'm trying:

```
Future<Parking> fetchParking() async {
    final response = await http.get('/*A confirmed working api adress*/');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Parking.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load parkings');
    }
  }
```

And a Location example:

```
void _getUserLocation() async {
  var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();
  _setLocation(location);
}
```

Comment: `print('before get'); final response = await http.get(...); print('after get');` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Okay the api request seems fine, I was calling it in the wrong place but there's still the same issue with the .getLocation().
My log only prints "Before get"

Comment: Can you try wrapping in a try-catch block then print the error?

Comment: This is where I have no idea what to do. I have followed this https://pub.dev/packages/location and all the permissions are there, I have the right dependencies etc.

Edit: I'll try that James, thanks

Comment: they say in the README: `_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();` so is it enabled in your case?

Comment: Tried adding the permissions from the README but nothinfg changed and the try-catch doesn't print any errors...

Comment: That gives me `flutter: true`

Comment: Starting to think I will need to do a reinstall of the whole shebang

Comment: and what about the streaming way, did you try it? `location.onLocationChanged.listen(print);`

Comment: Nothing is printing but then again im emulating on a macbook connected to a wifi so my location shouldn't be changing.

Comment: ok i missed you run it on the emu... so most likely the emu should not provide any location at all? why it should return anything valid from `await _locationTracker.getLocation();`?

Comment: Hmm I was assuming it should return my laptops location. My colleague is having no issues running an android emulator with Location.

Comment: and does ios simulator have any built-in location app? if so, does it show anything? afaik android emulator has an extra way to manually input fake location and by default does not show any location at all (but maybe that changed recently)

Comment: Hm yeah you're right. I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the support this far pskink!

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw you must have an iphone or android real device, dont you? if so, give it a try!

Comment: I'm sure he has an parsing error inside `Parking.fromJson`, need to ass try-catch block inside this method to see what exactly exception throwing

Comment: This was never resolved but the issue was somehow related to Xcode or iOS because I ran it on Android AVD instead and it works fine.